# Can Clojure Korma produce WITH - RETURNING query in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, clojure, korma, sqlkorma

I'm trying to reproduce this query from the Postgres docs:

```
WITH moved_rows AS (
    DELETE FROM products
    WHERE
        "date" >= '2010-10-01' AND
        "date" < '2010-11-01'
    RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO products_log
SELECT * FROM moved_rows;
```

Can Korma actually do it (besides just writing raw SQL, of course)? I see no mention of it in the docs.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After diving into Korma source code, I've noticed that it generates queries by itself. Then I've grepped through the Korma source code and it has no `RETURNING` keyword in it:

```
$ grep -ri returning .
$
```

So I came to a conclusion that unfortunately currently Korma doesn't support `WITH`-`RETURNING` Postgres' syntax.

What you could do next is to contact Korma developers in their [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sqlkorma).

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully executed a similar query, an `UPDATE` with the `RETURNING` keyword, using the [`exec-raw`](http://sqlkorma.com/docs#misc) function.